# Drawing on a players X & Y value instead of JFrames X & Y value

Tags: java

So, I'm creating a game for fun (just a simple 2D game.) I'm having trouble drawing a box with Graphics2D around my player. I believe the issue is that its trying to draw the box on the JFrame's X & Y value instead of my players X & Y value.

Here's an example,

```
public void render(Graphics2D g)
{
    double playerXX = this.x;
    double playerYY = this.y;

    g.drawRect((int) playerXX, (int) playerYY, 60, 60);
}
```

Instead of drawing a box that's 60 x 60 around my player, it draws a box at the X & Y value of the player at the X & Y value of the JFrame. Meaning you cant even see the box because my X & Y for my player are a few thousand.

I've tried casting the double to an int and vice versa and I've tried moving my level higher up on the image.

Comment: `because my X & Y for my player are a few thousand.` So how do you draw the player?

Comment: My player gets drawn by a constructor from my tileMap class that uses graphics g